# why Gradient its not editable in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Im using Illustrator and I have used gradient on different paths now I need to edit them but it seems I cant do anything on those paths anymore. one of the paths the gradient arrow doesn't even appear and on the rest i can see the arrow but cant change anything anyone knows what the problem is or what have i done wrong? this is how it looks lie when i click on gradient nothing appears on one path[image]

Comment: Hello mahsa, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question! This sounds most like a product support question, and you'd be way better off asking about those in the [Adobe Illustrator forums](https://forums.adobe.com/community/illustrator). Because of this, this question might be put on hold soon. Please, don't be discouraged, we are aware that using this site can be a learning curve, but we *are* happy to have you. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

I think it may get rasterized, you may go to Window-->Appearance--> Fill type is shown gradient or not?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to know without looking at the file, but could it be a [gradient mesh](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/illustrator-growing-gradient-mesh-tomato.html) and not a regular gradient?

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting to see the **Gradient Annotator** you won't if you have multiple objects selected. The Gradient Annotator only appears for single objects, groups or multiple-object selections do not show the annotator.

However, even if the annotator is not showing you can still use the **Gradient Tool** or the **Gradient Panel** to adjust the gradient. The annotator is only *one way* to adjust a gradients, not the *only* way.